# How can I exclude rows from two tables whose values are encompassed by each other?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following two tables, Table A and Table B.

What I'm trying to do is return a result set where:

1. If the start position (only) in Table B is between the start and end position of any row in Table A, then I don't want that row from Table B to be in the result set.
2. If any of the start and end positions in Table A are between any of the start and end positions of any row in Table B, then I don't want that row from Table A.

Here is Table A:

| RID | StartPos | EndPos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 45 | 77 |
| 7 | 118 | 130 |
| 7 | 197 | 212 |
| 7 | 218 | 235 |

Here is Table B:

| RID | StartPos | EndPos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 83 | 87 |
| 7 | 121 | 132 |
| 7 | 175 | 179 |
| 7 | 183 | 191 |
| 7 | 195 | 214 |
| 7 | 221 | 237 |

Here is my desired result set. You can see that 197 and 212 from Table A fall between the row in Table B that has 195 and 214, so that row from Table A isn't in the result set. You can also see that the start position 221 in Table B is between a range in Table A (218, 235), so that row from Table B isn't in the result set either.

| RID | StartPos | EndPos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 45 | 77 |
| 7 | 83 | 87 |
| 7 | 118 | 130 |
| 7 | 175 | 179 |
| 7 | 183 | 191 |
| 7 | 195 | 214 |
| 7 | 218 | 235 |

In sum, I want to exclude where:

- TableA start pos and end pos are between any of table B's start pos and end pos.
- TableB start pos is between any of table A's start pos and end pos.

Also, there are more than one RIDs in the table...
I thought (and still think) I could get this done using a FULL join (or maybe using APPLY), but I'm getting a little stuck, which is why I'm asking you all for some help on it!

Here is the T-SQL to generate the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #TableA(
    RID int NULL,
    StartPos int NULL,
    EndPos int NULL
)

INSERT #TableA (RID, StartPos, EndPos) VALUES (7, 45, 77)
INSERT #TableA (RID, StartPos, EndPos) VALUES (7, 118, 130)
INSERT #TableA (RID, StartPos, EndPos) VALUES (7, 197, 212)
INSERT #TableA (RID, StartPos, EndPos) VALUES (7, 218, 235)


CREATE TABLE #TableB(
    RID int NULL,
    StartPos int NULL,
    EndPos int NULL
)

INSERT #TableB (RID, StartPos, EndPos) VALUES (7, 83, 87)
INSERT #TableB (RID, StartPos, EndPos) VALUES (7, 121, 132)
INSERT #TableB (RID, StartPos, EndPos) VALUES (7, 175, 179)
INSERT #TableB (RID, StartPos, EndPos) VALUES (7, 183, 191)
INSERT #TableB (RID, StartPos, EndPos) VALUES (7, 195, 214)
INSERT #TableB (RID, StartPos, EndPos) VALUES (7, 221, 237)


SELECT *
FROM #TableA

SELECT *
FROM #TableB
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to you question, I think this is what you want:

```
select * from #TableB b 
where not exists (
    select 1 from #TableA a 
    where b.StartPos between a.StartPos and a.EndPos
    and A.RID = b.RID
)
union
select * from #TableA a 
where not exists (
    select 1 from  #TableB b
    where a.StartPos between b.StartPos and b.EndPos
    and a.EndPos between b.StartPos and b.EndPos
    and A.RID = b.RID
)
;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8d1b8c84e951293e696d6a2300aa6108)

Comment: Those two rows should be included because, only if the entire range in Table A falls within a range in Table B should the rows be excluded. 118-130 isn’t fully within any range in Table B. The same goes for 218-235. Therefore those rows should be in the result set. Does that help at all?

Comment: Without investigating it further, it may be sufficient to change or to an in 2leg of union. I have updated the answer

Comment: Quick question. Would this solution take into account multiple different RIDs? I need to partition by the RID...

Comment: Just add the predicate a.RID =, b. RID to both EXISTS

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!

Comment: `union all` surely?

Comment: @charlieface, why would you need a duplicate row?

Comment: Because they are two completely different tables. We don't know what these tables represent because no real names are given, but in all likelihood they are fundamentally different things and the duplicate rows will be wanted. They will probably have other columns which will be selected which will prevent duplication anyway. Using `union` means you force the query to de-duplicate.

Comment: I agree that we know nothing about what the resulting relation represent. I disagree that that would imply that union all would surely be prefered over union.

Comment: I suppose you're right, let's not jump to conclusions. But I will just say that most examples I've seen of `union` on SO and DBA are case where `union all` should have been used instead. A lot of people don't even realise that `union` will distinct at the same time. It's basically the same issue as `join, join, join` followed by `distinct`, the query writer hasn't really thought about what the result actually represents, and is just de-duplicating without thinking